# PHP fgets loads CPU to 100%

Tags: php, stream, cpu, stdin

I've made read key press function in PHP. The code sets non-block stream mode for STDIN and in `while` waits when STDIN will receive any data. It works, but I noticed that function loads CPU to 100%. How much is bad this code for CPU and is there any another way to check is STDIN contains any data?

```
    $stdin = fopen("php://stdin", "r");
    stream_set_blocking($stdin, false);
    system("stty cbreak -echo");

    while (true)
    {
        if ($keypress = strtoupper(fgets($stdin)))
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    stream_set_blocking($stdin, true);
```

Comment: you are having a
    `while (true)` loop .

Comment: You mean only `while (true)` loads CPU to 100%, not fgets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem was resolved after I added `time_nanosleep` for 5 milliseconds on each loop iteration:

```
$stdin = fopen("php://stdin", "r");
stream_set_blocking($stdin, false);
system("stty cbreak -echo");
$t = 1000000;
while (!($keypress = strtoupper(fgets($stdin))))
{
    time_nanosleep(0, 5 * $t);
}
stream_set_blocking($stdin, true);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: If you find yourself doing this in PHP, it is a sign that PHP is a terrible fit for the problem you are solving, and you should consider using a different language